# FXML filechooser failing to be reopened

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have the following code running on a button press in Java using FXML

```
void run(){
            FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
            FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("MP4 files (*.mp4)", "*.mp4");
            fc.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);
            fc.setInitialDirectory(videoFile);
            videoFile = fc.showOpenDialog(stage);

}
```

The first time I call this code it works as intended, opening a file choosing dialog in windows and returning a handle to the file however if I attempt to open a new file with the same code nothing occurs and this error is thrown.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Folder parameter must be a valid folder

Which seems to indicate that it is immediately failing to open the dialog. Does anyone know the reasoning behind this and a possible fix?

Edit:

I was improperly calling setInitialDirectory for anyone who may need the answer in the future.

Comment: is videoFile a file rather than a directory/ folder?

Comment: The variable name of `videoFile` indicates it holds a file, not a folder. The error message says "_Folder parameter must be a valid folder_". These two things combined indicate setting `videoFile` as the `initialDirectory` is incorrect. Perhaps you meant `fc.setInitialDirectory(videoFile.getParentFile())`?

Comment: I appreciate the guidance I seemed to have just been on autopilot and missed that entirely, thank both of you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Folder parameter must be a valid folder

The value passed to `setInitialDirectory` must be a directory. It seems `videoFile` is a file not a directory/ folder.